# EMI shielding for VFD and DC PSU's for CNC controller

Tags: power-supply, emc, motor-controller, vfd, cnc

The plan was to mount a VFD (Spindle) and (x3) 48V Power supplies on MDF and near it I want to mount 4 TB6600's for motion controlling a CNC machine. I would like to make it enclosed with some small fans for cooling.

I will be using cable glands on the AC side but I want to use aviation connectors for the penetrations on the DC Stepper and signal side, the steppers will be wired with shielded 18/4, while the limit switches will be going through a low pass filter on the control board also maybe shielded.

How to shield the DC side from the AC poison in the same controller box?

Comment: AND how to continue the shielding through the aviation connectors?

Comment: There is no need to comment on your own question. There is an edit link right under it. Keep all relevant information in the question rather than sprinkled through the comments. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: why do you want to use 38999 connectors? they are very VERY expensive for what they are. Sure jamnut is convenient in that environment but still

Comment: The look and it locks securely. And 12 cost me $20. Not too bad. (im looking for a method to properly separate the ac from dc in the same enclosure. Dividers or not.)

Answer (score 1):

I would be most concerned about noise from the VFD motor wiring. That should be shielded and kept away from all other wiring. Check to see what the VFD manufacturer's literature says about electromagnetic compatibility.

I would also be concerned about proper cooling of everything in the enclosure.

I suspect that the power level of the VFD is quite a bit higher than the other components. I would recommend not putting it in the same box with other equipment without more experience. I don't think that anyone will tell you that it is easy and risk-free if your only guidance is advice provided via the internet based on a vague description or perhaps even a detailed description of the equipment and the planned arrangement.